# Retrieving the full path of a registry entry

Tags: vb.net, software-distribution

enter code hereI am using VS2013 in VB on Windows 10. I have written an installation time routine (`Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)`) that saves a value in the registry via (`SaveSetting("XIndustries", "APP1", "TypeOfInstallation", "01")`).

After the install the application queries this value to check the installation. All versions of Windows prior to 10 work fine. Now the application receives a null value. I need to find where the installer is putting the value so I can find it. So I thought that retrieving the hierarchy where it was saved would be a good start. Anyone have any ideas or is there a better way?

Thanks, Jim

```
 Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
    MyBase.Install(stateSaver)


    Dim X1, X2, A3 As Short
    Dim A1, A2, A4 As MsgBoxResult
    Dim SW As Boolean = vbFalse
    ComputerName = My.Computer.Name

    'Add initialization code after the call to InitializeComponent
    Try
        Dim webservice As New biz.palatineindustries.www.Service1
        webservice = New biz.palatineindustries.www.Service1
        webservice.Timeout = 60000
        If My.Computer.Name.ToString.Length > 2 Then
            If My.Computer.Name.ToString.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper = "FBI" Then
                A1 = MsgBox("Use PRODUCTION Website?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
                Select Case A1
                    Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                        webservice.Url = "http://www.auctioncharitysoftware.com/service1.asmx"
                    Case Else
                        webservice.Url = "http://www.palatineindustries.biz/service1.asmx"
                End Select
                A4 = MsgBox("Use computer name other than " & ComputerName & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
                Select A4
                    Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                        Dim newFrm As New Form
                        Dim txtbox As New TextBox
                        AddHandler txtbox.TextChanged, AddressOf txb_TextChanged

                        newFrm.Controls.Add(txtbox)
                        newFrm.ShowDialog()
                        MsgBox(ComputerName)
                End Select
            Else
                webservice.Url = "http://www.auctioncharitysoftware.com/service1.asmx"
            End If
        Else
            webservice.Url = "http://www.auctioncharitysoftware.com/service1.asmx"
        End If
        Dim str As String = webservice.UpcomingAuctions
        Dim CurrentAuctions() As String = Split(str, "|")
        '    MsgBox("Going to web service: A3 = webservice.TypeOfInstall(" & ComputerName & ",)")
        A3 = webservice.TypeOfInstall(ComputerName, Nothing)
        '   MsgBox("Web returned:" & A3)
        Select Case A3
            Case PC.PCType.InitialMasterInstall
                SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.InitialMasterInstall, String))
                '          MsgBox("InitialMasterInstall SET: " & PC.PCType.InitialMasterInstall)
            Case PC.PCType.MasterSoftwareUpdate
                SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.MasterSoftwareUpdate, String))
            Case PC.PCType.InitialSlaveInstall
                SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.InitialSlaveInstall, String))
            Case PC.PCType.SlaveSoftwareUpdate
                SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.SlaveSoftwareUpdate, String))
            Case PC.PCType.Unknown
                For X1 = 0 To CurrentAuctions.Count - 2 Step 2
                    A1 = MsgBox("Is this " & CurrentAuctions(X1) & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
                    Select Case A1
                        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                            SW = vbTrue
                            Exit For
                    End Select
                Next
                If SW = vbFalse Then
                    SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.Unknown, String))
                Else
                    '  MsgBox("Sending this to the web: Computername - (" & ComputerName & ") Auction Name - (" & CurrentAuctions(X1 + 1) & ")")
                    X2 = webservice.TypeOfInstall(ComputerName, CurrentAuctions(X1 + 1))

                    ' MsgBox("Got this back from the web: (" & X2 & ")")
                    Select Case X2
                        Case PC.PCType.InitialMasterInstall
                            SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.InitialMasterInstall, String))
                        Case PC.PCType.MasterSoftwareUpdate
                            SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.MasterSoftwareUpdate, String))
                        Case PC.PCType.InitialSlaveInstall
                            SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.InitialSlaveInstall, String))
                        Case PC.PCType.SlaveSoftwareUpdate
                            SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.SlaveSoftwareUpdate, String))
                        Case PC.PCType.Unknown
                            SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.Unknown, String))
                        Case Else
                            MsgBox("Got this back from the web, and this is an error: (" & X2 & ")")
                    End Select
                End If
            Case Else
                '   YIKES
                SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.InitialMasterInstall, String))
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("2. " & ex.Message)
        SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", CType(PC.PCType.InitialMasterInstall, String))

    End Try
    '   MsgBox(GetSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation") & " is the type of install")
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to show us more code than that if we're going to be able to help you. For example how does the application save and check the registry key?

Comment: The installer saves the entry with the following instruction:  SaveSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation", "01"). After install the application retrieves it with the following instruction:  Dim RegistryTypeOfInstallation As Object
            RegistryTypeOfInstallation = GetSetting("PalatineIndustries", "Auction", "TypeOfInstallation").  The results of the retrieve is null.

Comment: Is that as close as you get? You have no source code whatsoever to this installer? Well there's no way to tell why you're getting a null return from a few method names. So yes, I guess you'll have to search for the key in some way...

Comment: Sorry, I added the code. I didn't think it would help much since the actual value displays properly when I uncomment the last msgbox.